# JOGL on linux no glcontext and XInitThreads()

Tags: java, linux, opengl, debian, jogl

im trying to build my JOGL project for linux here but eclipse console shows:

> Info: XInitThreads() called for concurrent Thread support

and *bamm* the opengl context is not created...

java -version:

> java version "1.6.0_26"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: the problem is NOT code related! (at least not the java code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To being able to help we would need more information, 
as described in our Wiki:
  http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_FAQ#Bugreports_.26_Testing

After following our bugreport recommendations, we would have your test case
and the advertised log files sent by you. Either use our forum/mailinglist or bugzilla.
When done, you may be so kind and update this issue here at stackoverflow.

Note: Indeed, if your test fails with one of our test cases, it is most likely a JOGL problem. The most obvious test would be to try to run a native opengl demo ensuring its functional on your machine. However, please follow above procedure, then we maybe able to help. ~Sven